# Can't create migration in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, database-migration, asp.net-core-2.0, sqlclient, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to create Identity migration is ASP.NET Core 2.0 and getting error.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "MarketIdentity" requested by the login. The login failed.

Appsettings.json

```
"MarketIdentity": {
  "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MarketIdentity;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Data:Market"));

        services.AddMvc();

        //app database
        services.AddDbContext<EfDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:Market:ConnectionString"],
            b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Market")));

        //identity database
        services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:MarketIdentity:ConnectionString"],
            b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Market")));

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MarkIdentity": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MarketIdentity;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}

services.AddDbContext<EfDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MarkIdentity")));
```